# Can't access to Asus Router's Firmware after enabling WPS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I fooling around with the settings at the GUI firmware page and after I enabled WPS, I keep getting this message whenever I log into http://router.asus.com/

[in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h091C.png)

is there a way to disable wps without tampering with the router physically? I don't wanna risk by fo

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it, I downloaded the ASUS Device Discovery app on my phone and was able to log back into the router through http://192.168.1.33/ and disable WPS, it seems http://router.asus.com/ got replaced by the IP